# how to draw custom custom circle inside rectangle shape using custom view in android

Tags: android, view

how to draw custom custom circle inside rectangle shape using custom view.after drawing it should be expand the rectangle shape when ever you drag the edges of that rectangle.**how to draw custom custom circle inside rectangle shape using custom view.after drawing it should be expand the rectangle shape when ever you drag the edges of that rectangle**

Answer (score 0):

You need to use drawRect, drawOval/drawArc for this. Read more from here:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html